# Setting up PDO connection class for Microsoft Access Database

Tags: php, sql, database, ms-access, pdo

Good day!

Basically, I'm trying to set up a PDO connection class with a Microsoft Access database with PHP so I can call the class when I'm creating new pages.

So far I have this, i've tried to adapt it from other articles on Stack Overflow:
NB: I'm completely new to setting up PHP with a Microsoft Access database and I know my $dbName is probably in the wrong place and I'm not sure where it goes to be honest!

```
class connection{

    public $con = '';

    function __construct(){

        $this->connect();   
        /*probably in the wrong place but... */ 
        $dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "\database/yakety1new.mdb";
    }

    function connect(){

        try{

            $this->con = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=Admin; Pwd=;");

            $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        } catch (PDOException $e){

            echo 'We\'re sorry but there was an error while trying to connect to the database';
            file_put_contents('connection.errors.txt', $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }   
}
```

So what I'm trying to find out is where the $dbName variable goes and also how I would I could call the connection class in an index page along with an SQL statement.

I have a basic idea, something along these lines:

```
include_once '/pages/classes/connectionClass.php';

$con = new connection();

$sql = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM celebs");
$result = $con->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $firstname = $row['firstname'];
    $surname = $row['surname'];

echo $firstname;
echo $surname;  
}
```

I run the script and I just get this message:
'We're sorry but there was an error while trying to connect to the database'

Can anyone please point me in the right direction, any help would be absolutely awesome!
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Ok, now I'm getting really lost - I've been looking at my code and can't figure out why i'm getting the error:  Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in D:....... on line 23. Here's the code now:

```
try{

   include_once '\classes\connectionClass.php';


   //get the DB connection
   $con = new connection();
   $pdoConnection = $con->connect();

    //query the DB
   $sql = $pdoConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM celebs");
   $result = $pdoConnection->query($sql);
   while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
      echo $row['firstname'];
      echo $row['surname'];
    }

    } catch (Exception $e){
      echo 'ERROR:'.$e->getMessage();
      file_put_contents('connection.errors.txt', $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
    }
```

The error is relating to this line:
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't think you should mix the `/` and \ in your connection database name string http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/ and as a matter of fact, you could probably just put the database name, not it's actual file path, like there http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.connection.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**connection** class

```
class connection{

    private $con;
    private $dbName;

    function __construct(){
        $this->dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "\database/yakety1new.mdb";
    }

    function connect(){
        $this->con = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$this->dbName; Uid=Admin; Pwd=;");
        $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $this->con;
    }   
}
```

and the **code**:

```
try{
    include_once '/pages/classes/connectionClass.php';

    //get the DB connection
    $con = new connection();
    $pdoConnection = $conn->connect();

    //query the DB
    $sql = $pdoConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM celebs");
    $result = $pdoConnection->execute();
    while ($row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['firstname'];
        echo $row['surname'];
    }
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo 'ERROR:'.$e->getMessage();
    file_put_contents('connection.errors.txt', $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. 
I can't seem to get this to work :( i've made the amendments you've suggested and i'm getting an internal server error

Q: After the last line of code you've suggested ($result = $pdoConnection...) do you reckon the rest of my code is ok?

Comment: Hi @TimJohnstone if you have multiple records then you should use `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`. what is the error you are getting

Comment: Unfortunately mate, i'm still getting the same error message. Where would you put the return value? perhaps that's where I'm going wrong?

Comment: the error you showed in your post is the one you wrote, what about the PDO one? `$e->getMessage()`

Comment: the PDO error message ('We're sorry but there was an error while trying to connect to the database') was resolved after I put the code: $dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "\database/yakety1new.mdb"; in the connect() function...when i've implemented your changes it gives a '500 internal server error' message and no results are being displayed. If it's not too much trouble please could you re-write my code how you mean for it to be changed as i'm trying out both yours and 'developerwjk' approach and not getting any results :( thank you

Comment: @TimJohnstone sure check my edit, please make sure you can connect succesfully I have never tried PDO with access, I wouldnt know about the connection string

Comment: Thank you very much for doing that meda, very kind. Unfortunately, when I turn on Firebug and reload the page im still not seeing any results and i'm still getting the message "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error" - pointing towards the code page which uses the class - I know the Access syntax is correct, proper scratching my head over this one! Do you have any idea why im getting a 500 error? i know it's a hard to pin point an error like this one..

Comment: Hello meda, upon looking at the errors, im getting one fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object on line 23...   while ($row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

Comment: I think the query is returning false, you can check `if($result){while...}else{echo "error in query";}` also the back slash on the access path I suspect this , maybe it should be `/` ?

Comment: Tim If you ever need me you can leave me a comment or email me cybermeda@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks very much, meda. That's very kind of you!

Answer (score 0):

$dbname either needs to be a local variable of the function that actually uses it, or needs to be defined as a member of the class.  As it stands, you have it as a local variable of a function that doesn't even use it.  And you should use a naming convention that distinguishes between members and local variables, possibly by using m_ in front of class members:

```
class connection
{
  public $m_con = '';
  private $m_dbName = '';
  function __construct()
  {
     ...
     $m_dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "\database/yakety1new.mdb";
  }
  function connect()
  {
    try 
    {
      $this->m_con = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$m_dbName; Uid=Admin; Pwd=;");
```

Or

```
 function connect()
 {
   try 
   {
     $dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "\database/yakety1new.mdb";
     $this->con = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=Admin; Pwd=;");
```

Comment: thank you very much for you response, however i'm getting a code hint error from after:
$this->m_con = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$m_dbName; Uid=Admin; Pwd=;");

its not liking this:

 $this->m_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: I've tried implementing your suggestions and i'm getting the error message...

'We're sorry but there was an error while trying to connect to the database'